# Sending actual destination path from nginx module to backend

Tags: nginx

For uploading a file to a server I am using nginx upload module. What I understood from the docs is that it saves the uploaded file to a temporary directory and only provides information about the file to backend(python bottle server in my case) via POST and information that should be passed to backend can be specified by upload_set_form_field directive.

How can I send the actual destination path to backend ,Since nginx will store in some temporary path and not to the path where the uploading was meant to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. Should set upload_pass_form_field directive value in nginx config to  regex pattern matching destination path field name.